# When user registers, the session variables aren't being stored

Tags: php, session

On my site, I have an issue when a new member registers, it should direct them to their profile page and their data should pull up.

Currently it does take them to their profile page, except it says "That user does not exist." because it seems that it is not saving the session variables. If I log this new member out and log them back in, then everything works correctly with a new session.

What is causing this? Here is some code that may help with solving the issue - if you need more code, please let me know. Just FYI the path is that they go to the register.php page and then are redirected to the profile.php page, so I will also provide the profile.php code.

function is:

```
//adds a user to the database
    function add_user($user, $pass){
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user));
    $pass = sha1($pass);   
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `user_password`) VALUES ('{$user}',     '{$pass}')");
    }
```

Code for register.php is:

```
<?php

include('core/init.inc.php');

$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['repeat_password'])){
if (empty($_POST['username'])){

    $errors[] = 'The username cannot be empty.';    
}

if (empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['repeat_password'])){

    $errors[] = 'The password cannot be empty.';
}

if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['repeat_password']){

    $errors[] = 'Password verification failed.';
}

if (user_exists($_POST['username'])){

    $errors[] = 'The username you entered is already taken.';
}

if (empty($errors)){
    add_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    $_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($_POST['username']);

    header('Location: profile.php');
    die();
}
}
?>
```

profile.php code is:

```
<?php 

include('core/init.inc.php');    
if (isset($_GET['uid']) && $_GET['uid'] !='')
{
$user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['uid']);
}
else
{
$user_info = fetch_user_info($_SESSION['uid']);
}    
?>
```

the function fetch_user_info is:
    //fetches profile information for the given user
    function fetch_user_info($uid){
        $uid = (int)$uid;

```
    $sql = "SELECT
                                    `user_name` AS `username`,
                                    `user_firstname` AS `firstname`,
                                    `user_lastname` AS 'lastname',
                                    `user_email` AS `email`,
                                    `user_about` AS `about`,
                                    `user_location` AS `location`,
                                    `user_gender` AS `gender`
                            FROM `users`
                            WHERE `user_id` = {$uid}";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

init.inc.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$exceptions = array('register', 'login', 'find', 'profile');

$page = substr(end(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])), 0, -4);

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('user_system');

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

include("{$path}/inc/user.inc.php");


if (isset($_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE['password']) && isset($_SESSION['username']) === false){

    if ($uid = valid_credentials($_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE['password'])){

            $_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($_COOKIE['username']);
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
            setcookie('username', $_COOKIE['username'], time() + 604800);
            setcookie('password', $_COOKIE['password'], time() + 604800);
    }
}

if (in_array($page, $exceptions) === false){

 if (isset($_SESSION['username']) === false){

           header('Location: login.php');
           die();
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()`?

Comment: No, I didn't have that called out on register.php or profile.php but I just tried adding that and it didn't fix the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

First, does `include('core/init.inc.php');` (or some other file) contains `session_start()` Without calling `session_start()` your `$_SESSION` will be empty.

Second: I never see you assigning `$_SESSION['uid']`. Do you redirect to your profile with `$_GET['uid']` ?

Because in registration.php, you are setting `$_SESSION['username']` and then doing the redirect. You may want to also set `$_SESSION['uid']` there before doing the redirect.

Comment: let me figure out how to show you the extra code. I'll post it shortly.

Comment: I also added $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['user_id']; before the redirect on register.php but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: can you please do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and check, if there is an `uid` set?

Comment: If I do a vardump and I register a new user, it says the profile does not exist, but the vardump says: array(1) { ["username"]=> string(4) "test" } and "test" is the name of the new account I made.

Comment: I added a request to get the uid and now it says:
array(2) { ["username"]=> string(5) "test2" ["uid"]=> NULL } 

The request I added was:  $_SESSION['uid'] = $_GET['uid'];

Comment: @soshannad I think you're messingit up a bit. take a breath and retry ;-) if you don't have `GET` or `POST` for `uid`, you are assigning `null` values. you could modify `add_user();`to return the `uid` the added user has and assign this to the session var before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

First, try this in add_user :

```
//adds a user to the database
function add_user($user, $pass){
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($user));
    $pass = sha1($pass);   
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `user_password`) VALUES ('{$user}',     '{$pass}')");
    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Second, in register.php  :

```
[...]
if (empty($errors)){
    $_SESSION['uid'] = add_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($_POST['username']);

    header('Location: profile.php');
    die();
}
```

Make sure you have session_start() in all pages that need to access the session.

Hope it helps!